# SlickGrid Header menu - multiple selection for a single column

Tags: javascript, jquery, grails, slickgrid

I have been using SLickGrid in my grails application but for now i am only able to tag a column just with one option from the menu drop down.
the js code for this is :-

```
var headerMenuPlugin = new Slick.Plugins.HeaderMenu({buttonImage:window.params.dropDownIconUrl});
headerMenuPlugin.onBeforeMenuShow.subscribe(function(e, args) {
 var menu = args.menu;
 var i = menu.items.length;
 var iconClass = undefined
 menu.items[0].iconCssClass = (args.column.name === $("#sciNameColumn").val())?'icon-check':undefined
 menu.items[1].iconCssClass = (args.column.name === $("#commonNameColumn").val())?'icon-check':undefined
 });

 headerMenuPlugin.onCommand.subscribe(function(e, args) {
 var name = args.column.name;
 if(args.command === 'sciNameColumn') {
  if(args.column.name == $('#sciNameColumn').val())
  name = ''
  if(args.column.name == $('#commonNameColumn').val())
    $('#commonNameColumn').val('');
    $('#sciNameColumn').val(name);
   } else if(args.command === 'commonNameColumn') {
   if(args.column.name == $('#commonNameColumn').val())
      name = ''
   if(args.column.name == $('#sciNameColumn').val())
     $('#sciNameColumn').val('');
     $('#commonNameColumn').val(name);
    }
     selectNameColumn($('#commonNameColumn'), commonNameFormatter);
     selectNameColumn($('#sciNameColumn'), sciNameFormatter);
    });
    grid.registerPlugin(headerMenuPlugin);
```

But now the requirement is that i need more than one selection for a column from the drop down and save the selections and use it later on and also same selections can be done for multiple columns.

Hope i am clear enough, Thanks for any support

Answer (score 0):

What I did is change the headerMenu plugin to introduce two features:

- a new item option, `keepOpen`, which prevents the menu to close after a command, and
- refreshing the item details (specifically `iconImage` and `iconCssClass`) after a command (only if the menu was kept open).

I'll try to set up the pull request on the SlickGrid repo if I find the time.